# Problems using spring @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot

I have three methods on my project annotated with @Scheduled, being one of them a cron expression and the other two are fixed delay. The annotations look like:

Method 1:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 20000)
@Async
protected void checkBrokenEngines() {
```

Method 2:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
@Async
public void checkAvailableTasks() throws Exception {
```

Method 3:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 2 * * ?")
protected void deleteOldData() {
```

Previously I had a problem that when the `checkBrokenEngines` and `checkAvailableTasks` methods were slow to be executed, the next executions did not happen until the previous one ended. Reading the documentation and some topics here from the StackOverflow, I saw that my project had some wrong **pool size** settings and the methods were not annotated with **async**. (Async was for the next execution start even if the old one doesn't end, as this does not cause any problems in my application)

Now another problem has come up, which is my question:

When the `deleteOldData()` method is executed, neither of the other two methods will run until it finishes. After seeing that this method was blocking the execution of the other two, I annotated the method as async and after that, even if this method takes time to be executed, the other two are always invoked correctly within the stipulated time. Why? In my understanding, this should not happen since those methods are noted with async and the pool has enough space to execute them.

PS: `deleteOldData()` cannot be async. It must start just after the previous execution has been completed.

**EDIT 1:**

Async executor config:

```
@Override    
public AsyncTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
    log.debug("Creating Async Task Executor");
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(10000);        
    return new ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor(executor);
}
```

Comment: Did you check Thread.currentThread() name if deleteOldData() was still under same thread pool?  Maybe you need pass customThreadPoolExeuctor to all those two @Async("myThreadPool")  and leave this deleteOldData() to run on the default thread pool. With this you may be able to achieve what you are intended to.

Comment: @Rajeev Probably the method "deleteOldData" is executing in the same thread pool, otherwise, it wouldn't be a problem. I did what you said before posting this question. I create another thread pool just for "deleteOldData()" and it worked properly, but it seems to be a workaround, don't you think?

Comment: Could you share the spring config where you have configured the pool ?

Comment: @user2683814 I've updated my answer, you can check it under "EDIT 1".

Comment: Hi @CristianoBombazar, right now I don't have the time to elaborate on my answer so I'll just leave a comment, because of the deletion it seems to me that you have conditional work-flows on the tasks. I can advise you to take a look at Spring State Machine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**All** `@Scheduled` marked invocations will use the default single thread executor to schedule tasks (async or otherwise).

All `@Async` tasks are handed off to different aysnc threadpool executor for executions with AOP interceptor.

I think your confusion comes from the fact async methods return **immediately** but when deleteOldData is run, it is running synchronously as there is only one thread, it blocks the execution of any other scheduled tasks.

Because you have default threadpool (single thread) for the scheduled tasks they are scheduled one after the another.

> The other methods annotated with @Async they execute even if it
>   finishes or not. In some cases, I have two methods of executing at the
>   same time. But when deleteOldData is executing, the async methods stop
>   to run until it finishes. This what I'm not understanding, sorry :/ –

This is different from scheduling - This is where your async executor comes into play and they are run concurrently.

You can fix this in one of two ways:

You can use `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=10`  in application properties to set the pool size of task scheduler.

Alternatively, use different tasks schedulers. Keep using default scheduler for `@Scheduled` task and configure something like below for async tasks ( remove scheduled annotation )

There is an enhancement requested to pass task scheduler to the `@Scheduled` annotation until then you have to schedule tasks manually.

Register a new task scheduler for async invocations and schedule the methods in the post construct stage. Something like

Configuration

```
@Bean("asyncTaskScheduler")
public TaskScheduler asyncTaskScheduler() {
  return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
}
```

Services

```
@Autowired
private TaskScheduler asyncTaskScheduler;

@PostConstruct
void schedule() {
  asyncTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::checkAvailableTasks, 20000L);
  asyncTaskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedDelay(this::checkBrokenEngines, 20000L);
}

@Async
public void checkBrokenEngines() {...}

@Async
public void checkAvailableTasks() throws Exception {...}
```

Comment: Your example I think it clarified my mind. All answers seem to be right, but I didn't understand why. Before your answer, my workaround was having two executors, one for async methods and other for non-async methods, because I didn't know that all scheduled methods use the same executor even if they are async or not, because of thought creating an async executor (as I posted in my question) will handle async methods and non-async methods will be handle by default executor (which the default pool size is 1). One more question: To schedule async methods is your answer the right way?

Comment: I prefer first way i.e increase pool size for scheduler so it can handle all your tasks.

Answer (score 6):

Scheduled tasks are processed by the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`, which has a **default pool size of 1**. Only when they are annotated as `@Async`, execution is passed into the `AsyncTaskExecutor`, which for you configured a dedicated executor with a larger pool size.

To configure the `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` within a `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler(){
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("ThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
    scheduler.setPoolSize(50);
    return scheduler ;
}
```

Comment: One should add that OP's own comment _deleteOldData() cannot be async_ is based on incorrect assumptions. This kind of behavior should be handled by locks inside the method and with OP's own missed trigger handling logic (i.e. what should happen if previous execution did not finish)... this is something Spring AFAIK does not offer.

Comment: You can simply this and just use `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=1` in application properties without needing the bean defined. for thread prefix `spring.task.execution.thread-name-prefix=ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`

Comment: Do you mean that my method `deleteOldData' is not executing in the same thread pool as the others one?

Comment: Async are being executed in async thread pool, scheduled methods without async are executed in task executor pool. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableScheduling.java#L101

Comment: @PavelHoral I got this part, but I didn't understand why the other async methods don't execute while `deleteOldData`is executing since they use different thread pool as you said. Even if the thread pool is full, I think is a hell coincidence that other methods start when `deleteOldData` finishes.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar -  There is only one scheduler ( ThreadPoolTaskSchedular ) to schedule tasks async or not. So with default being 1 ( single thread ) it can only schedule one task at any given moment. This is what I think anyways.

Comment: As @user2683814 says... if scheduler is using only one thread and that thread is being busy running your method, then it can not invoke other methods. Doesn't matter if they are async or not.

Comment: @user2683814 The other methods annotated with `@Async` they execute even if it finishes or not. In some cases, I have two methods of executing at the same time. But when `deleteOldData` is executing, the async methods stop to run until it finishes. This what I'm not understanding, sorry :/

Comment: @CristianoBombazar I think your confusion comes from the fact async methods return immediately so it appears that they are running in parallel ( or frequently )  but when deleteOldData is run it is running synchronously as there is only one thread it blocks the execution of any other scheduled tasks. If you like you can rework your example to use two separate schedulers one for sync and one for aysnc tasks. Updated the same in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because @Async task is submitted by default Scheduling executor and its size is 1 by default.

I have modified  submit method of the `AsyncTaskExecutor` executor:

```
  @Bean
    AsyncConfigurer asyncConfigurer() {
        return new AsyncConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public AsyncTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
                ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor(){
                    @Override
                    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
                        System.out.println("async task was started by thread -- "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        return super.submit(task);
                    }
                };
                executor.setThreadNamePrefix("custom-async-exec");
                executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
                executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
                executor.initialize();
                return executor;
            }
        };
    }
```

And output.

```
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
async task was started by thread -- scheduling-1
```

So as there is 1 thread into default Shedulers pool `scheduling-1` and whenever its busy can't start/submit new `@Async` tasks. define `@Bean` [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) or add `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=x`.

EDIT

Here is simple test for visualization:

```
@Component
    public static class Jobs{
        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1500)
        @Async
        public void job1(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1500)
        @Async
        public void job2(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Scheduled(initialDelay = 10000, fixedDelay = 5000)
        public void blocking(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

visualization from `visualvm`

[image]

Red 'arrows' shows the point `blocking()` job kicks in. and while `scheduling-1` `Thread` blocked on this there is no way to submit `job1()` and `job2()` also

Comment: It makes sense, but, I have some doubts about it. See my comments under @PavelHoral answer.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar  We have here one thread  `scheduling-1`, at first the only job it was doing was submitting  `checkBrokenEngines()` or `checkAvailableTasks()` tasks to your AsyncExecutor. this operation was cheap and `scheduling-1` was almost always free and happy. Then you have added new task to this thread `deleteOldData()` now it  `scheduling-1`has to do this job which is blocking, while this job is processing scheduling-1 is not able to submit/trigger other tasks to AsyncExecutor.

Comment: @CristianoBombazar I have added screenshot from visualvm

Answer (score 2):

Just "1 more aspect":
Cite: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async#the-async-annotation

> First – let's go over the **rules** -  `@Async` has two limitations:
>
> - it must be applied to **public methods only**
> - **self-invocation** – calling the async method from within the same class – **won't work**

side note: 
<- same rules apply to `@Transactional`, ... annotation(s).

> The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. And self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

`@Scheduled protected void ... ()` is ok on the other hand, since ([again, thx to  baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks#overview)):

> The simple rules that need to be followed to annotate a method with `@Scheduled` are:
>
> - a method should have void return type
> - a method should not accept any parameters

Please check, whether any issues/misunderstanding exist after applying to `@Async` rules and considering the other [correct - very nice] answers. (baeldung and @Nonika use `public` methods!)

[The Baeldung `@Scheduled` article, offers also this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks#schedule-a-task-at-a-fixed-rate):

> ... Note that scheduled tasks don't run in parallel by default. So even if we used fixedRate, the next task won't be invoked until the previous one is done.
>
> **If we want to support parallel behavior in scheduled tasks, we need to add the @Async annotation:**

```
@EnableAsync
public class ScheduledFixedRateExample {
  @Async
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
  public void scheduleFixedRateTaskAsync() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(
      "Fixed rate task async - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  }
}
```

> *Now this asynchronous task will be invoked each second, even if the previous task isn't done.*

**my note**: *Of course* the asynchronous jobs **can block** each other on some "common resource" (file/object/db/lock/semaphore/etc.) ...which could lead to problems/"full pools"/deadlocks... you should clear it out, before deciding for `@Async`.

And, since no further word about *configuration*...i "assume/hope", it works "out of the box"/as documented.

So, still few information cannot be seen from here:

- self-invocation?
- "synchron inside"?