# Spring Boot: gracefully shutdown by controlling termination order involving MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, multithreading, spring-boot, shutdown-hook

I have a Spring Boot application that spawns many threads using an `AsyncTaskExecutor` (the number is predefined)

The threads execute an infinite loop, that reads from some queue and process objects, so I don't really have a rejection policy mechanism (like a ThreadPool that accept `tasks`)

The problem is that when the application gets closed, threads might (and probably) be busy with processing an item which includes operations to Mongo using `MongoTemplate`.

So when the application gets closed the MongoClient is being `close()`'d automatically and then I'm getting some errors from Mongo, like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The pool is closed
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ConcurrentPool.get(ConcurrentPool.java:137)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.getPooledConnection(DefaultConnectionPool.java:262)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:103)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:92)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:85)
```

How can I close the application gracefully? e.g. interrupting the threads while not shutting down the MongoClient just yet?

**CODE:**

Bean creation:

```
@Bean
AsyncTaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
    SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor executor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    return executor;
}
```

Execution simply by:

```
executor.execute(runnable);
```

Comment: Show how you spawn the threads. You should be able to Override isInterrupted and do a graceful disconnect from mongo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` - SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor creates a new thread for each request instead use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and configure two properties noted below.

```
/**
 * Set whether to wait for scheduled tasks to complete on shutdown,
 * not interrupting running tasks and executing all tasks in the queue.
 * <p>Default is "false", shutting down immediately through interrupting
 * ongoing tasks and clearing the queue. Switch this flag to "true" if you
 * prefer fully completed tasks at the expense of a longer shutdown phase.
 * <p>Note that Spring's container shutdown continues while ongoing tasks
 * are being completed. If you want this executor to block and wait for the
 * termination of tasks before the rest of the container continues to shut
 * down - e.g. in order to keep up other resources that your tasks may need -,
 * set the {@link #setAwaitTerminationSeconds "awaitTerminationSeconds"}
 * property instead of or in addition to this property.
 * @see java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#shutdown()
 * @see java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#shutdownNow()
 */
public void setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(boolean waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown) {
    this.waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown = waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown;
}

/**
 * Set the maximum number of seconds that this executor is supposed to block
 * on shutdown in order to wait for remaining tasks to complete their execution
 * before the rest of the container continues to shut down. This is particularly
 * useful if your remaining tasks are likely to need access to other resources
 * that are also managed by the container.
 * <p>By default, this executor won't wait for the termination of tasks at all.
 * It will either shut down immediately, interrupting ongoing tasks and clearing
 * the remaining task queue - or, if the
 * {@link #setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown "waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown"}
 * flag has been set to {@code true}, it will continue to fully execute all
 * ongoing tasks as well as all remaining tasks in the queue, in parallel to
 * the rest of the container shutting down.
 * <p>In either case, if you specify an await-termination period using this property,
 * this executor will wait for the given time (max) for the termination of tasks.
 * As a rule of thumb, specify a significantly higher timeout here if you set
 * "waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" to {@code true} at the same time,
 * since all remaining tasks in the queue will still get executed - in contrast
 * to the default shutdown behavior where it's just about waiting for currently
 * executing tasks that aren't reacting to thread interruption.
 * @see java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#shutdown()
 * @see java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService#awaitTermination
 */
public void setAwaitTerminationSeconds(int awaitTerminationSeconds) {
    this.awaitTerminationSeconds = awaitTerminationSeconds;
}
```

Relavant part

> Set the maximum number of seconds that this executor is supposed to
>   block on shutdown in order to wait for remaining tasks to complete
>   their execution before the rest of the container continues to shut
>   down. This is particularly useful if your remaining tasks are likely
>   to need access to other resources that are also managed by the
>   container.

You can configure using spring auto configuration to control the task execution properties (**preferred**) or programmatically with `@Bean` annotation

Spring boot in 2.1.0 provides auto configuration for task executors and uses for both `@EnableAsync` and Spring MVC Async support.

There is no task executor bean / webMvcConfigurer configuration is needed from application. So remove the one you have and should be good.

You can adjust using applicaion properties/yml file with `spring.task.execution.*`.

```
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=60
```

Full listing can be found [`here`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)

More details [`here`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20751) and [`here`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1563)

OR

```
@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(5); 
    taskExecutor.waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(60);
    return taskExecutor;
  }
```

Comment: I actually used ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with these parameters. The thing is that I'm still getting errors from the mongo client, requiring me to try-catch the IllegalStateException every time I'm using MongoTemplate let's say. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: That is odd. If you could share an example reproducing your issue (preferably github project) then I could take a deeper look and also please update your post to show what you have right now. More details are needed. Could you use @Async annotation to run your tasks ? Also how are these tasks scheduled ? You have to let spring manage the tasks for you.

Comment: Some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617040/problems-using-spring-scheduled/60782153#60782153)

Comment: I'll try @Async as you suggested

Comment: Sagar, can you please give a brief explanation how @Async would solve the issue?

Comment: Once you mark the method as `@Async`,  when the method is invoked  it will run in separate thread ( thread borrowed from threadpool ) and managed by spring. So once your spring boot is shutting down it will gracefully finish the thread executing the task. You will need `@EnableAsync` to enable async processing.

Comment: @SagarVeeram sorry but Spring does not gracefully shutdown async task. I've tested and the async thread is interrupted before it get completed.