# How to gracefully shutdown spring boot app using configuration and programatically?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, async-await, graceful-shutdown

I want to gracefully shutdown my spring boot application. I wanted to know what is the difference between configuring it via application.yaml file and programmatically ?

in my application yaml file, i have added this from reference https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-web-server-shutdown:

```
server:
  shutdown: graceful
spring:
  lifecycle:
    timeout-per-shutdown-phase: 30s
```

and in my code i am also using threadPoolTaskExecuter because I am using `@EnableAsync` annotation:

```
@Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(30);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-");
    executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

where i added **executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(30)**
so my question is do we need both ways to configure it or not? and what is the difference? Also I found that we have other configuration available from spring from here:
[Spring Boot: gracefully shutdown by controlling termination order involving MongoClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61187699/)

```
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=60
```

this is confusing to me. Can someone please explain the different ways ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: its interesting perhaps there are two types. One for the controllers and other for the async processes.